# Expected end of statement sql and sessions

Tags: sql, sql-server, session, vbscript, asp-classic

this is my first question on stackoverflow, I hope someone can help me.

I am making a website similar to facebook.
heres my sql.

```
    readsql = "SELECT * FROM post INNER JOIN ubuser ON (post.pos_USERID = ubuser.usr_ID) WHERE ubuser.usr_ID == '"session("ID")"'"
```

and heres the error im getting

> Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0401'
>
> Expected end of statement
>
> /student/S0215538/newsfeed1.asp, line 22

```
readsql = "SELECT * FROM post INNER JOIN ubuser ON (post.pos_USERID = ubuser.usr_ID) WHERE ubuser.usr_ID == ' "session("ID")" ' "
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

I cant see why I am getting this error, if i comment out the WHERE onwards, it works, but its not what I need.

thanks in advance

Thanks everyone, that was fast.
I always forget the &, and the people who mentioned the == should be =, you were also right. 
it fixed that error, however i now have a new error saying "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" in this line `post.Open readsql, connection, adOpenkeyset, AdLockOptimistic`
"post" is my recordset and "connection" is the adodb connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needs to be

```
readsql = "SELECT * FROM post INNER JOIN ubuser ON (post.pos_USERID = ubuser.usr_ID) WHERE ubuser.usr_ID = '" & session("ID") & "'"
```

Problem is your syntax, strings need to be terminated with double quotes `"` and concatenated correctly using ampersand `&` in VBScript. Also remove the `==` and replace with `=` as RedFilter suggested.

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation required `&`:

```
readsql = "SELECT * FROM post INNER JOIN ubuser ON (post.pos_USERID = ubuser.usr_ID) WHERE ubuser.usr_ID = '" & session("ID") & "'"
```

Also use only one `=` in your query.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
readsql = "SELECT * FROM post INNER JOIN ubuser ON (post.pos_USERID = ubuser.usr_ID) WHERE ubuser.usr_ID = '" & session("ID") & "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate (&) the variable session("ID") into the string:

```
>> set session = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
>> session("ID") = "whatever"
>> readsql = "SELECT * FROM post INNER JOIN ubuser ON (post.pos_USERID = ubuser.usr_ID) WHERE ubuser.usr_ID ==
 '" & session("ID") & "'"
>> WScript.Echo readsql
>>
SELECT * FROM post INNER JOIN ubuser ON (post.pos_USERID = ubuser.usr_ID) WHERE ubuser.usr_ID == 'whatever'
>>
```

(Are you sure that your DBMS' SQL dialect uses "==" for comparisons?)

Comment: He's using [tag:asp-classic] the ID he is setting is coming from the `ASPSession` object.

Comment: @Lankymart - yes, I faked the session object using a dictionary to get an executable code fragment

Comment: I realise that, I just think you are more likely to confuse the OP doing that as he will attempt to implement your code, unless it's made clear it is just a test case so you could execute his code personally.